# Google OAuth 2 authorization - Error: redirect_uri_mismatch - Youtube API v3

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, youtube-api

```
$data = array('code' => $code,
    'client_id' => '...', 
    'client_secret' => '...',
    'redirect_uri' => 'http://localhost/youtube/cookie_token.php',
    'grant_type' => 'authorization_code');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$return = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $return;
```

As you can see in this [screenshot from Google Console](http://prntscr.com/8ndlzd), the URL has been registered in the application.

Comment: Please ask your question in English.

Answer (score 0):

OF COURSE you should not use "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 in any OAuth scheme.

EDIT:

Well, of course it might work, but you have to change javascript origin and authorized redirect uri to localhost in `console.developers.google.com` under the client id you are using here.

Comment: "OF COURSE you should not use "localhost" or 127.0.0.1 in any OAuth scheme"... Completely untrue. Always use this in *Development* environments.